# Cookie updates with PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I'm writing a simple script to store a language cookie.

When a user selects a language, I'd like the cookie to be updated accordingly.

For some reason this doesn't work - once the cookie is created, it won't update.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if($_REQUEST['language']) {
$language = $_REQUEST['language'];
setcookie('language', '', time()-3600);
setcookie('language', $language, time()+3600);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Cookie language</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $_COOKIE['language'];
?>
<ul>
<li><a href="delete.php?language=en">en</a></li>
<li><a href="delete.php?language=de">de</a></li>
<li><a href="delete.php?language=es">es</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you call `setcookie()` twice? You don't need to delete the cookie and set it again. Just this line will do the job:

```
setcookie( 'language', $language, time()+3600 );
```

It will update the cookie's value and time.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code works fine, but the $_COOKIE array is not updated until the next request :)

```
if($_REQUEST['language']) {
$language = $_REQUEST['language'];
setcookie('language', '', time()-3600);
setcookie('language', $language, time()+3600);
$_COOKIE['language'] = $language;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[As per definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) `$_REQUEST` in an associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.

In other words your `$_GET['language']` gets overwritten by `$_COOKIE['language']` resulting in `$_REQUEST['language']` equal to `$_COOKIE['language']`.

If you replace `$_REQUEST` with `$_GET` in your code it will work as you expect:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['language'])) {
    $language = $_GET['language'];
    setcookie('language', $language, time()+3600);
    // setcookie() doesn't update $_COOKIE
    $_COOKIE['language'] = $language;
}
?>
<title>Cookie language</title>
<?php echo $_COOKIE['language']; ?>
<ul>
<li><a href="delete.php?language=en">en</a></li>
<li><a href="delete.php?language=de">de</a></li>
<li><a href="delete.php?language=es">es</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing in there that definitely can't work: you are calling `$_COOKIE` right after `setcookie()`. Have a look at the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php). There is written:

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on the next page
>   load with the $_COOKIE

So you will only have access to the cookie on the next request. Use

```
echo $language;
```

instead.

Comment: It is true, but not the case. If you bother to actually run the code, you'll see that you're wrong.